# FULLTEXT not working

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have altered the table with

```
ALTER TABLE store_products ADD FULLTEXT(product_name, product_desc);
```

Now I am using this query

```
SELECT * FROM store_products WHERE MATCH(product_name, product_desc) AGAINST('abc' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This is my

```
product_id  bigint(20)  NO  PRI     auto_increment
product_name    varchar(150)    YES MUL     
product_desc    text    YES         
product_price   varchar(10) YES         
product_discount    varchar(10) YES         
product_views   bigint(20)  YES         
product_date    varchar(29) YES         
product_quantity    int(11) YES         
product_img_url varchar(250)    YES         
product_code    varchar(15) YES         
store_id    bigint(20)  YES         
product_category    int(11) YES         
product_image1  varchar(150)    YES         
product_image2  varchar(150)    YES         
product_image3  varchar(150)    YES         
sale_id bigint(20)  YES     0   
product_image4  varchar(150)    YES
```

And engine is

```
MyISAM and table_collation utf8_general_ci
```

I am running MySQL 5.7 but whenever I run fulltext search query I get no rows. Can anyone help what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning no rows does not mean that the fulltext index or search does not work, it only means that no matching data was found. This shows an issue with the data or the search expression, therefore we need to focus on these.

1. The sample search expression is `abc`, which is 3 characters long. As MySQL documentation on [Boolean fulltext searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) says:

> The minimum and maximum word length full-text parameters apply to
>   FULLTEXT indexes created using the built-in FULLTEXT parser and MeCab
>   parser plugin. innodb_ft_min_token_size and innodb_ft_max_token_size
>   are used for InnoDB search indexes. ft_min_word_len and
>   ft_max_word_len are used for MyISAM search indexes.

The default value of `ft_min_word_len` is 4 characters, therefore the `abc` will be ignored in the search. This is probably the 1st reason why you do not have any matches. You can lower the limit to 3, but then you need to drop and rebuild the fulltext index.

2. Searching for `abc` returns only those records only that contain the word `abc`, but will not return those records that only contain the word `abcd` or `babc`. You may not have the searched word in the data. You need to understand that the fulltext search is not the same as `like '%abc%'`.